non-question reply as a technical dialog, but more than a comment
Background:
A made this question years ago:
AIC on Savitzky-Golay width
This is a great answer, look at the mathjax, the graphs, and the code.
AIC on Savitzky-Golay width
Request:
I want to reply to it, but a comment can't support the answer.
I want my reply to contain:

an update on the code, but using R (ggplot2, ...)
an engagement of the updated derivation of the cross-validation error
reproducible inputs (seed, explicit code) so we can look at the same data
Code for the plots.  I liked the plots, so I want to be able to reproduce them. (impo)

That is outside the architecture of the CV or SE architecture, but the only requirements are a formalism for linking, and permission to not contrive everything as a question.
Is there a way that technical contributors can dialog in a sophisticated manner here without creating a new question?

Edit your post! Simply add your update to the said answer in your question. If the author wants to respond, it would be in their answer. At least that is how I perceive the situation. If really needed, you can share mails but that is outside the purview of SE.

And I feel such type of feature request has to be made at the parent Meta SE. But that is only my opinion.

Grey area, but it sounds like this might work as a new answer. Doesn't directly address with the 'dialogue' aspect you are interested in (for which SE is not well suited, as you note), but you could tag the other author in a comment below the new answer.

The third point, "reproducible input", can be added in an edit of the question.

I am not sure what the point is of adding code?

@SextusEmpiricus - Reproducibility requires it.  Specificity is the soul of good communication, especially technical conversations.  If I want to understand or run forward, then I have to be able to work up to the current point with no functional flaws, and the ability to get myself here without help.  Think for a minute about the AI's training on SO for code development.  They are learning to interpolate at a better level than many humans.  Right now, humans can extrapolate well, but it takes time to set it up so it works well. Humans need to be able to discover, or they become redundant.

@EngrStudent I don't understand what you practically mean with 'adding code'. You are the question asker, why do you want to share code? Is it about asking other people to review and debug your code related to the question and have them say whether it is correct?

@SextusEmpiricus - debug my code??  This is not SO, and even if it were, that is both lazy, and like building headlights out of chandeliers, very ugly.  The purpose of the code is to share methods and ideas.  If I want to talk about some method, to use an old one lets pick Gaussian Mixture Models, then having specific examples of data allows me to determine if my EM and AIC are converging to the "truth" when estimating model parameters given samples created with a "seed".  A good question should have input data, reproducible code, and all, but good things that aren't questions use them too.

@EngrStudent so, you want to add code to an answer or question? But what is the problem with that? Why does it need a seperate technical dialog? You are not thinking about just adding code to the question as here  https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%223d%22+user%3A164061 ?

Or do you want to ask the person that answered for code? You can do that like here: the animation is very nice, Can you share the code of making it?

"an update on the code, but using R (ggplot2, ...)" This sounds like giving an answer with a different code example. You can use an answer for that.

I remembered that I once gave an answer where I rewrote python in R, it is here https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/329456/164061 but in that case the answer entails more than just a rewriting of the code.

I also remember, but it is more difficult to find because I didn't do it myself, several times where the person that is asking the question is also providing an answer to their own question as a sort of review of the other answers and as a sort exercise to see whether they understood it. Sometimes that includes a specific example solution to the problem with a code or computation that relates to their specific data.

@SextusEmpiricus - There are 5 ways to communicate the same mathematical idea, but like all languages, mileage varies in each of them.  (https://youtu.be/NJYoqCDKoT4?feature=shared) <-- for your consideration.  It is truer in mathematics, which needs widest fluency than it is in poetry.  Word problems, symbolic/algebraic manipulation, flowcharts/diagrams/graphs, charts/plots, and tables of numbers.  Right now the structure is a forest of stumps, not capable of discussion only Q->A with sprinkling of comments.  It is max-depth, max hopcount, of 1. "OTTFFSS_", what comes last, isn't "O_".

@User1865345 - I don't know how to do that.  If the question can be moved, can the comments (which are impo pretty good) also be moved with it?

Are you suggesting to "move" this query to Meta @EngrStudent?

@User1865345 - you suggested that was a more appropriate fit.  I do not know if it is or isn't.  Lots of people know less than 0.1% of knowable technical knowledge that requires any advanced formalism to communicate. I could see it fitting in a dozen STEM areas, and arguably there are federal contracts about STEM education that could fund the whole thing, but most of commercial/industry has a zero competency or capability with grants.

What I stated was that since you suggested a completely new feature that supports the required demands, you need to raise such feature request at Meta.SE as the local mods or for that matter any other relevant agent won't be able to implement it for a single community. Secondly, I guess such type of medium is not there for SE wasn't envisioned to be a lengthy forum like ecosystem, instead it was modelled as a Q&A concise structure.

I sincerely believe you can edit your question addressing the said answer and leave a comment for the author to check your update with respect to their answer. @EngrStudent

@User1865345 -  I like the question and the answer as they are, and I feel modifying them would lose value.  I could add a follow-on, but that would be a very weak connection, and does not have a strong connection to the (excellent) answer, and anyone looking at links would also miss the good other answers.

In general, I am not in favor of changing a question too much so as to lose its original spirit of query. But here, the edit is meant to frame a response you have with respect to a certain answer. This would, in fact, elevate the context and quality of the thread, imo. @EngrStudent

BTW, having a quick glance at your comments to that answer (not my field of study) seems to indicate this warrants altogether a new query @EngrStudent
